# Move radio type input to the right of label

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I have to build a form that has radio-type input to the right of the text (text-label) without changing the order of input-tag and label tag.

As the id's for input and label are being set dynamically and maybe due to this reason changing the order is not working instead the radio button is getting vanished. But I am not finding a way to do it.

Below is the code I wrote and the image of the desired outcome.

My code outcome:

[image: image of code output]

Code below (it's a ruby on rails syntax):

```
<div class="options">
  <input type="radio" id="<%=qid%>op1" name="<%=qid%>" value="<%= @questions[qid]["option1"] %>">
    <label class="option-value" for="<%=qid%>op1">A. <%= @questions[qid]["option1"] %></label>
  </div>
```

And the desired style I want to give

[image: desired outcome]

I also tried writing the input[type"radio"]  after the label-tag but it's still not happening.
I also tried applying `float:right` css to input[type="radio] but it's not working either.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without more code, I would suggest you to change your markup to have the input in second, but you didn't provide much to work with.

Comment: Tip: Never use `&nbsp;` `&emsp;` `<br>` etc for styling. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Tip: Stop using inline `style` attributes. Use your stylesheet instead.

Comment: `user-select` is `auto` by default. Why all those overrides?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have edited the question to look more neat and clean. Also, I will apply those next time I code. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Class `options` would be better as *singular* `option`, and `option-*` for the children elements of your atom.
- You could use `<label>` as the wrapper an therefore no need to use `for` and `id` attributes
- Don't use inline `style`
- Use display `flex` on the label parent
- Use `margin-right: auto` on the `SPAN` to distance it from the `INPUT` element

```css
.option {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.option-value {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<label class="option">
  <span class="option-value">B. Owners</span>
  <input class="option-input" type="radio" name="Q2" value="Owners">
</label>
```

Tip:
when in need to change the markup order visually, use [CSS `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) (if in a *grid* or *flex* context)

```css
.option {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.option-value {
  margin-right: auto;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<label class="option">
  <input class="option-input" type="radio" name="Q2" value="Owners">
  <span class="option-value">B. Owners</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for putting so much effort. I would request you to see the question again as I did an edit.

Comment: @LabaniDas you're welcome. All my suggestions in my answers reflect your edit as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to place the label before input in HTML as

```
 <div class="options" style="user-select: auto;">
    <label class="option-value" for="Q2op2" style="user-select: auto;">B. Owners</label>
    <br style="user-select: auto;">
    <input type="radio" id="Q2op2" name="Q2" value="Owners" style="user-select: auto;">&nbsp;
  </div>
```

and add some CSS

```
.options{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always place the tags in the order that you want to view them. As you need text to appear first here, place the input tag first and then the radio button.
As you need spacing between the two components, make the div container flex and space them evenly.

```
<div class="options" style="user-select: auto;" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <label class="option-value" for="Q2op2" style="user-select: auto;">B. Owners</label>      
    <input type="radio" id="Q2op2" name="Q2" value="Owners" style="user-select: auto;">&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and to the point :)